# Why is the outline of Insula Dracon still Red?

Tags: just-cause-3

I have just finished liberating Insula Dracon, but the outline of the region is still red, despite all the provinces being free.

Why is this the case? It seems confusing as this is not the case with Insula Fonte.

[image: Insula Dracon]

Comment: Looks like you still have a couple of story missions...

Answer (score 1):

To turn a comment into an answer, you need to do more story missions:

> Looks like you still have a couple of story missions... –
> HorusKol
> Aug 14 '20 at 13:10